# Failed to compile ./src/components/Chat/Chat.js Module not found: Can't resolve './components' in

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github

**Failed to compile
./src/components/Chat/Chat.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components' in 'C:\Users\VISHAL\Desktop\Chat-app\lets_meet\client\src\components\Chat'**

[image: my directories order]

I am  copy this project from github but it is showing error..... i didn't copy whole project just copy some of the pages...

[the link of the github from where i copied the code is](https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_chat_application)

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`Chat.js` is trying to import `component.js` from the Chat folder which doesn't exists. Navigate to the correct path where the `component.js` file located.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is giving this type of error because i forgot to make a file inside message folder message.js ,Now it's working fine .I think if there is any missing file then it will give error like that .... Sorry for made a common mistake.